# Loging into microsoft account using ROPC flow without any user interaction

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, openid

We are writing a script that on executed uses the ROPC flow to authenticate user login into Microsoft account without any UI, by giving the user credentials and retrieve access token. The main goal is to login and display users mails by using Microsoft graph API.
We have tried this with a UI by redirecting user to Microsoft login page and it works but we want a non-interactive way of achieving this.

```
    const AccToken= await pca.acquireTokenByUsernamePassword(usernamePasswordRequest)
```

After encountering the above line in code it is giving me the following error:

[Wed, 21 Sep 2022 08:02:47 GMT] : @azure/msal-node@1.14.0 : Info - acquireTokenByUsernamePassword called
[Wed, 21 Sep 2022 08:02:47 GMT] : @azure/msal-node@1.14.0 : Verbose - initializeRequestScopes called
[Wed, 21 Sep 2022 08:02:47 GMT] : [749ab7af-b49a-4154-9ea1-773f778b1190] : @azure/msal-node@1.14.0 : Verbose - buildOauthClientConfiguration called
[Wed, 21 Sep 2022 08:02:47 GMT] : [749ab7af-b49a-4154-9ea1-773f778b1190] : @azure/msal-node@1.14.0 : Verbose - building oauth client configuration with the authority: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant_id}](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTenant_id%7D)
[Wed, 21 Sep 2022 08:02:47 GMT] : [749ab7af-b49a-4154-9ea1-773f778b1190] : @azure/msal-node@1.14.0 : Verbose - createAuthority called
/home/abc/Desktop/git/ExpressWebApp/node_modules/@azure/msal-common/dist/index.cjs.js:509
_this = _super.call(this, errorString) || this;
^

ClientAuthError: endpoints_resolution_error: Error: could not resolve endpoints. Please check network and try again. Detail: ClientAuthError: openid_config_error: Could not retrieve endpoints. Check your authority and verify the .well-known/openid-configuration endpoint returns the required endpoints. Attempted to retrieve endpoints from: [https://login.microsoftonline.com/{Tenant_id}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration](https://login.microsoftonline.com/%7BTenant_id%7D/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration)

I would like to know why this is occurring or if there is any different approach that i can take for logging in without any user-interaction

Answer (score 0):

***The error*** **`Endpoints_resolution_error`** ***usually occurs if the endpoint/URL you are calling is not valid.***

Make sure to copy the **Endpoint** for OpenID like below:

[image]

- Please try using msal-node version **`1.9.0`** and check whether it resolves the issue.
- Check whether there is any **proxy setup** in your configuration that is blocking the contact to the endpoint URL.
- Try checking the **fiddler trace** and please debug the fiddler to check what's going wrong.
- If your application is multitenant then make use of `common/organizations/consumers` based on your requirement instead of **`tenant_id`** in the URL.

> **Please **note** that MSAL Node supports ROPC when the
> authorization server is OpenID compliant from this [**GitHub**](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/samples/msal-node-samples/username-password) blog.**

Try replacing the below line in your code to access the Graph API:

```js
const AccToken = await pca.acquireTokenByUsernamePassword({ scopes: [], password: config.userPassword, username: config.userAccount });
```

Check whether your **config/application parameters** match the below:

```js
auth: {
    clientId: "clientID",
    authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID",
    clientSecret: "clientsecret",
    knownAuthorities: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantID"
},
```